# How do I get an object (in React via POST) to save under the correct foreign key (Rails backend)?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, redux, react-redux, foreign-keys

I am building a React/Redux spa with a Rails backend. I am stuck with figuring out how to fix what seems to be a foreign key reassignment at POST request.

The association I have in the backend is Daycare  `has_many :toddlers` and Toddler `belongs_to :daycare`.

The schema shows that toddlers belong to daycares through the foreign key of `daycare_id`. For Daycare there are two objects in the database, with IDs of `1` and `2`. Obviously when I am creating a toddler, I will be choosing to save the toddler object in daycare with ID `1` or with ID `2`. When I go to create a toddler object via a form in the front end and save it to the second daycare, it saves by default to the first daycare.

Here is the `ToddlersController`:
as you can see in the `create` method, I have the toddler to be created only when the daycare exits. Also in the `params`, I have the `daycare_id` listed as an attribute.

```
class ToddlersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_daycare
  before_action :set_toddler, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /toddlers
  def index
    @toddlers = Toddler.all

    render json: @toddlers
  end

  # GET /toddlers/1
  def show
    render json: @toddler
  end

  # POST /toddlers
  def create
    @toddler = @daycare.toddlers.new(toddler_params)

    if @toddler.save
      render json: @toddler, status: :created, location: @toddler
    else
      render json: @toddler.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /toddlers/1
  def update
    if @toddler.update(toddler_params)
      render json: @toddler
    else
      render json: @toddler.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /toddlers/1
  def destroy
    @toddler.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_toddler
      @toddler = Toddler.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_daycare
      @daycare = Daycare.find_by(params[:daycare_id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def toddler_params
      params.require(:toddler).permit(:name, :birthday, :contact, :phone, :allergy, :daycare_id)
    end
end
```

Here is the `DaycaresController`:

```
class DaycaresController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_daycare, only: [:show]

  # GET /daycares
  def index
    @daycares = Daycare.all

    render json: @daycares, except: [:created_at, :updated_at], include: [:toddlers]
  end

  # GET /daycares/1
  def show
    render json: @daycare, except: [:created_at, :updated_at], include: [:toddlers]
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_daycare
      @daycare = Daycare.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def daycare_params
      params.require(:daycare).permit(:name, :address)
    end
end
```

Here is what is logged in the Rails server when I make the `POST` request:

```
Toddler Create (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "toddlers" ("name", "birthday", "contact", "phone", "allergy", "daycare_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "v"], ["birthday", "2019-01-06"], ["contact", "v"], ["phone", 7605551211], ["allergy", "v"], ["daycare_id", 1], ["created_at", "2021-10-10 20:20:40.385031"], ["updated_at", "2021-10-10 20:20:40.385031"]]
```

Here is the form in the React/Redux frontend. I had passed down the daycare IDs as props into the form component to attach them onto the form through the `select`. When I am filling out the form to create the toddler, the form that corresponds with the correct daycare logs in the console, indicating that I am in the right place.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { submitToddlers } from '../../actions/toddlerActions'

class DaycareForm extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            birthday: '',
            contact: '',
            phone: '',
            allergy: ''
        }
    }

    handleOnChange = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.value, "Daycare Form: handle on change")
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
    }

    handleOnSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        // let compareId = if ()
        // debugger
        this.props.submitToddlers(this.state, this.props.daycare.id)
        // debugger
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: ''})
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.daycare, "Day care id")
        console.log(this.props.getToddlers, "daycare_id")
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}>
                    <br />
                    {this.props.daycare.id}
                    <h4>New Student</h4>
                    <label><u>Name</u>: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleOnChange} value={this.state.name} placeholder="First name, last name..." required /><br />
                    <label><u>Birthday</u>: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="birthday" onChange={this.handleOnChange} value={this.state.birthday} placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD..." required /><br />
                    <label><u>Emergency Contact</u>: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="contact" onChange={this.handleOnChange} value={this.state.contact} placeholder="First name, last name..." required /><br />
                    <label><u>Phone</u>: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" onChange={this.handleOnChange} value={this.state.phone} placeholder="##########" required /><br />
                    <label><u>Allergy</u>: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="allergy" onChange={this.handleOnChange} value={this.state.allergy} placeholder="Allergy..." required /><br /><br />
                    <select name="daycare" id="daycare" required>
                        <option name="daycare_id">Select Daycare</option>
                        <option name="daycare_id" value={this.props.daycare.id}>Sunny Day Care</option>
                        <option name="daycare_id" value={this.props.daycare.id}>Tator Totts Academy</option>                   
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
}

//const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   //return {
        //getToddlers: state.toddlers,
        //loading: state.loading
   //}
//}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { submitToddlers })(DaycareForm)
```

Here is the `ToddlerActions` file. (When the debugger hits, this is the data that is shown after the `POST` request:

```
toddler:
allergy: "a"
birthday: "2019-09-02"
contact: "b"
created_at: "2021-10-10T17:56:22.079Z"
daycare_id: 1
id: 18
name: "c"
phone: 7605551278
updated_at: "2021-10-10T17:56:22.079Z"
```

As you can see the `daycare_id` is `1`)

```
export const submitToddlers = (toddler, daycareId) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
      fetch(`http://localhost:3000/daycares/${daycareId}/toddlers`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Accept": "application/json"
        },  
        body: JSON.stringify(toddler)
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(toddler => {
        debugger
        console.log(toddler, "submitting toddler")
        dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TODDLERS', payload: toddler })
      })
    }  
}

export const fetchToddlers = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'LOADING_TODDLERS'})
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/toddlers')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data, 'fetching toddlers')
        dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TODDLERS', toddlers: data })
      })
    }
}
```

How can I remedy the problem?

Comment: `submitToddlers` makes a request to `http://localhost:3000/daycares/${daycareId}/toddlers` isn't it? That request uses the DaycaresController (if any), not the Toddlers one. Can you share the code from DaycaresController (the whole file) and the logs when doing the request? You should see that in your Rails server at the moment of the request.

Comment: @SebastianPalma I added the Daycare controller as and the logs from the rails server above.

Comment: Um, `value={this.props.daycare.id}` ... You have this used twice in succession, not in a loop, but as static ... You'll need to fix that

Comment: As Jad mentioned, you have two inputs with `this.props.daycare.id` value, one for "Sunny Day Care" and another one for "Tator Totts Academy", the last value is the one that "wins", so you have to check which is repeated and/or which is the one you really expect the new record to belong to @IfeoluwaAkinremi-Wade.

Comment: @SebastianPalma i'm not sure i understand

Comment: See the option tags under the `daycare` select tag. You have two inputs with the same value attribute, check that's not causing the error.